# How can I remove an entire folder under Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem deleting my entire folder on firebase storage. I always get a 'storageRef.listAll is not a function' error when I specify the reference to the path. I would like to delete the complete path with all possibly existing images.

```
const storage = getStorage();

const storageRef = ref(
  storage,
  `${aktuellerUser._id}/artikelBilder/`
);

storageRef
  .listAll()
  .then((listResults) => {
    const promises = listResults.items.map((item) => {
      return item.delete();
    });
    Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

> error TypeError: storageRef.listAll is not a function

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the new Firebase Modular SDK where `listAll()` is a top level function and not a method on [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.storagereference.md#storagereference_interface). Similarly, you need to use `deleteObject()` to delete a file now instead of `.delete()` method as shown below:

```
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  listAll,
  deleteObject
} from "firebase/storage";

listAll(storageRef)
  .then(async (listResults) => {
    const promises = listResults.items.map((item) => {
      return deleteObject(item);
    });

    await Promise.all(promises);
  })
```